# Datadog trace in consumer queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, datadog

I have script consumer.php(listener queue from rabbit)

```
<?php

namespace App\Queue\Receivers;

class CronReceiver extends BaseReceiver
{
    public function handle(AMQPMessage $msg): void
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Consumer can work for a very long time (until an error or forced restart) [image]

only then will the traces get to datadog

I want to send a trace for each received message to datadog without restarting the script
Is this possible? can someone tell me how to do this?

i try

```
public function handle(AMQPMessage $msg): void
    {
        $tracer = new Tracer();
        $tracer->startActiveSpan('run');
        \DDTrace\GlobalTracer::set($tracer);
        //logic
        var_dump($tracer->getActiveSpan());
        $tracer->getActiveSpan()->finish();
        $tracer->flush();
    }
```

If I played around with these parameters, I was able to send traces immediately after the first iteration, but nothing arrived in subsequent iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.
I'm using datadog/dd-trace library

Now my code looks like this:

```
    public function handle(AMQPMessage $msg): void
{
        $tracer = new \DDTrace\Tracer();
        $scope = $tracer->startActiveSpan('run');
        $span = $scope->getSpan();
        $span->setTag('service.name', 'myServiceName');
        //logic queue consumer
        $scope->close();
        $tracer->flush();
}
```

Now I get each iteration of the script as a separate trace

[image]